# MATLAB xticlabel not rotating properly

Tags: matlab

I have followed the suggestion of using the xticklabel function at FEX website at:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486-xticklabel-rotate

However,

the last line of my code deletes my x-labels and shifts my graph to the right. I cannot understand where I am going wrong.

```
figure(3)
        j=bar3(x,c,width)
        set(gcf,'color','w');
        zlim([0 2000])
        set(gca, 'XTick',1:7, 'XTickLabel',{'label_1','label_2','label_3','label_4','label_5','label_6','label_7})
        set(gca, 'YTick',1:8, 'YTickLabel',{'1','2','4','8','12','16','20','24'})
        set(gca,'FontSize',10 ,'FontWeight','bold')
        text(15,-8  , '82,944 atoms', 'Color', 'k','FontWeight', 'bold','FontSize',12);
        view([-32 12])
        set(j,'LineWidth',1.5)
        xticklabel_rotate([1:7],1,{'label_1','label_2','label_3','label_4','label_5','label_6','label_7'})
```

Comment: The documentation you cited has the 'interpreter','none' option set. That could be important. Could you make your example code executable?it would be easier to help that way.

Comment: @Trogdor I am not sure what you mean. That code should execute except for just adding two variables x and c. x is just a column of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and c can be any 8x7 matrix. Does that help? I still have had no luck in properly rotating these tic labels for 3D

Comment: The `'interpreter','none'`-option has no effect here. I tried [this other contribution from MatlabCentral](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27812-rotate-x-axis-tick-labels/all_files) which rotates the labels but places them in the wrong spots.

Comment: @Schorsch Exactly, I found one that rotates, but puts them in wrong spot as well.

Comment: @JacksonHart, I didn't realize it was only short two variables, sorry I was just being lazy :P.

Comment: @Trogdor Do you know a solution to the problem?

Comment: unfortunately not at the moment. I may be able to look later, but it's nothing I've come across before